# Default init in Swift enum being ignored

Tags: swift, enums, initializer, option-type

I'm trying to reimplement `Optional` in Swift. I'm calling it `Maybe`. I have 2 inits, to create the empty or nil version and the one holding a generic type:

```
enum Maybe<T>{
    case Nothing
    case Something(T)

    init(){
        self = .Nothing
    }

    init(_ something: T){
        self = .Something(something)
    }

}
```

However, when I try to create an empty `Maybe`, the `init()` initializer is not called. Instead, the other one `init(_ something: T)` is called with `T = ()`.

What's going on? Why is the init without parameters being ignored?

```
var z = Maybe() // this calls init(_ something: T) with T = ()
```

Comment: And now swift 4 will not compile if you not explicit set the generate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift compiler needs some context to infer the type `T`, for example

```
var foo = Maybe<Int>()
var bar : Maybe<String> = Maybe()
```

The same problem would happen with

```
let x = Optional()
switch x {
case .None:
    println("None")
case .Some(let y):
    println("Some \(y)")
}
```

which prints `Some ()` and causes the compiler warning

```
warning: variable 'x' inferred to have type 'Optional<()>', which may be unexpected
```

Comment: Looks like you nailed it. However, I still don't understand why the compiler, when lacking information about the generic type, decides to ignore the first initializer... Any clues?

Comment: @cfisher: I noticed that if you have a *generic* function taking one argument `func foo<T> (x : T) { println(x) }` then you can actually call `foo()` and you get the same result as with `foo( () )`. So `var z = Maybe()` seems to be interpreted as `var z = Maybe( () )`. But I have no idea if then is intentionally or a bug.

Comment: @cfisher: I have posted a question at the developer forum https://devforums.apple.com/thread/250174, perhaps that gives some useful information.